# Using eloquent select related entries after restricting parent entry in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

If I have a laravel class, say Category, which has a 1:many relationship with another class, say Subcategory, How do I query *all* subcategories, with restrictions on the Category class?

For example, Query ALL subcategories where the Category class has the title "TEST".

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function subcategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Subcategory');
    }
}

class Subcategory extends Model {
    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

I've tried [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent) via:

```
    $subcategories = Subcategory::with(['category' => function($query)
        {
            $query->where('title', '=', 'TEST');

        }])->get();

// Returns ALL subcategories, with null where the category doesn't = TEST
```

I am interested in all methods of doing this!

edit -- Two solutions:

```
$data = Category::whereTitle('TEST')->first()->subcategories
//or equivalently:
$data = Category::whereTitle('TEST')->get()[0]->subcategories;
```

or within subcategory create a dynamic scope using @The Alpha's solution

```
public function scopeFromCategory($query, $type)
{
    return $query->whereHas('Category', function ($q) use ($type)
    {
        $q->whereTitle($type);

    });
}

// So you can later call
$data = Subcategory::FromCategory('TEST')->get();
```

Comment: Does it have to be a single query or can it be more than one? Additionally, what if more than one `Category` is matched by your criteria? Should your query return all subcategories of the multiple categories returned, or will there be only one Category matched?

Comment: Whatever works really, 1 or many queries. Ideally, it would be a single query similar to Category::find(1)->subcategories  but instead more like Category::findTitle('TEST')->subcategories. Either or, personally I only match one Category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
$subcategories = Subcategory::whereHas('category', function($query)
                 {
                     $query->where('title', 'TEST');
                 })
                 ->with('Category')
                 ->get();
```

This code will return the `SubCategories` including related `Category` but only if the related `category.title` is `TEST`. Also check the documentation about [querying-relations](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations).